# Using docker-sync for MySQL / Databases for local development?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, synchronization

I just learned about how docker-sync can help speed up local development work when on MacOS or Windows. It's much faster. However, I wondered if it also makes sense to use docker-sync for the database files?

I noticed that MySQL is still running quite slow when doing consuming tasks.

Comment: If you use a named volume for your database storage, you don't pay the MacOS bind-mount performance penalty.

Comment: I see. I do it like this:     volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

Comment: That should be fine; the database data stays inside the (hidden) Docker VM.  Crossing between that VM and the host is what's slow.

Comment: @DavidMaze I see. Any suggestions as to why my MySQL server might be slow then? (pretty sure it's the mysql server, as WP CLI commands that interacts with DB takes 2-3x longer time)